# LightningChart crashes when I draw a spectrogram using HeatmapGridSeries

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

While looking for a way to draw spectrograms in a web browser, I came across LightningChart.

[image]

I'd like to draw something similar to the one above using the community version of LightningChart.

Referring to LightningChart's API documentation and examples, I wrote the sample code like below.

```
// Create a XY Chart.
const chart = lightningChart()
  .ChartXY({
    container: "target",
  })
  .setTitle("LightningChart Spectrogram Test #1");

// Set the tick strategy for the x-axis to DateTimeTickStrategy
chart.getDefaultAxisX().setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.DateTime);

// Prepare sample data
const COLUMNS = 100;
const ROWS = 10;
const MAX_INTENSITY_VALUE = 360
const sampleData = Array.from({ length: ROWS }, () =>
  Array.from({ length: COLUMNS }, () => parseInt(Math.random() * MAX_INTENSITY_VALUE))
);

const start = { x: 0, y: 0.1 };
const step = { x: 2000, y: 0.39 };

// Create a series
const series = chart
  .addHeatmapGridSeries({
    columns: COLUMNS,
    rows: ROWS,
    start,
    step,
    dataOrder: "rows",
    heatmapDataType: "intensity",
  })
  // .setIntensityInterpolation("disabled")
  .setFillStyle(
    new PalettedFill({
      lookUpProperty: "value",
      lut: new LUT({
        steps: regularColorSteps(
          0,
          MAX_INTENSITY_VALUE,
          chart.getTheme().examples.spectrogramColorPalette
        ),
        interpolate: false,
      }),
    })
  )
  .setWireframeStyle(emptyLine);

series.invalidateIntensityValues(sampleData);
```

The above code works fine, but it's a little different from what I want.

When we call `series.setIntensityInterpolation("disabled")`(which is currently commented out) to get the desired result, nothing is plotted and the console displays as shown below.
[image]

I'm using LightningChart JS v4.1.0 and test on Chrome browser.

This is a crashing single HTML file I'm working on.
(I wrote this code based on https://github.com/Arction/lcjs-html-example)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Using chart in HTML page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Automatically support high DPI devices -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Flexbox styling to have the chart and header fill the page.
        Chart will take as much space as possible. -->
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .box {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .box .row.header {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
      }

      .box .row.content {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="box">
    <h1 class="row header">LightningChart Spectrogram Test #1</h1>

    <!-- Create div to render the chart into-->
    <div id="target" class="row content"></div>

    <!--IIFE assembly (lcjs.iife.js) is a standalone JS file, 
      which does not need any build tools, 
      such as NPM, to be installed-->
    <!--Script source must be defined in it's own script tag-->
    <script src="lcjs.iife.js"></script>

    <!--Actual chart related script tag-->
    <script>
      // Replace the contents of this script tag if you want to test code from our examples:
      // https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/

      // Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
      const {
        AxisTickStrategies,
        LUT,
        PalettedFill,
        Themes,
        emptyLine,
        lightningChart,
        regularColorSteps,
      } = lcjs; //Note: @arction/lcjs is not needed here, when using IIFE assembly

      // Create a XY Chart.
      const chart = lightningChart()
        .ChartXY({
          // Set the chart into a div with id, 'target'.
          // Chart's size will automatically adjust to div's size.
          container: "target",
        })
        .setTitle("LightningChart Spectrogram Test #1"); // Set chart title

      // Set the tick strategy for the x-axis to DateTimeTickStrategy
      chart.getDefaultAxisX().setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.DateTime);

      // Prepare sample data
      const COLUMNS = 100;
      const ROWS = 10;
      const MAX_INTENSITY_VALUE = 360;
      const sampleData = Array.from({ length: ROWS }, () =>
        Array.from({ length: COLUMNS }, () =>
          parseInt(Math.random() * MAX_INTENSITY_VALUE)
        )
      );

      const start = { x: 0, y: 0.1 };
      const step = { x: 2000, y: 0.39 };

      // Create a series
      const series = chart
        .addHeatmapGridSeries({
          columns: COLUMNS,
          rows: ROWS,
          start,
          step,
          dataOrder: "rows",
          heatmapDataType: "intensity",
        })
        .setIntensityInterpolation("disabled")
        .setFillStyle(
          new PalettedFill({
            lookUpProperty: "value",
            lut: new LUT({
              steps: regularColorSteps(
                0,
                MAX_INTENSITY_VALUE,
                chart.getTheme().examples.spectrogramColorPalette
              ),
              interpolate: false,
            }),
          })
        )
        .setWireframeStyle(emptyLine);

      series.invalidateIntensityValues(sampleData);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's wrong here, code looks OK, and I tested it locally and works with both intensity interpolation disabled and enabled.

I used LCJS build from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@arction/lcjs@4.1.2/dist/lcjs.iife.js

Otherwise no edits to the code you have in the question.

[image]

Comment: Walla! I was using the version 4.1.0 as I mentioned above. I've tried with the version 4.1.2 and it works for me too. Thanks for trying it and letting me know your results.

Comment: Ah I see, seems like this bug was patched. Good good.